# Pandas: Iterating over rows and adding list as columns with specific column title

Tags: python, pandas

I am iterating over rows of pandas dataframe, for each row I am generating a list (consisting of 8 elements). This list of 8 elements have different element for each row. I am trying to add this list to pandas dataframe as column for each row.

When I am trying to add as column the same list is added to all the rows. ideally specific list should be added to specific row. This is where I am stuck.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please show some sample input/output and code.